# Classification of $M_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$-submodules of $\mathbb{Z}^n$

Tags: modules

I recently saw
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686493/finding-submodules-of-a-module-over-a-ring-of-matrices) question and wanted to generalize it to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and matrices with integer coefficients. I think $k\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a submodule for any integer $k$. Is there a nice way to generalize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All submodules of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are of the form $k\mathbb{Z}^n$. Namely, if $S$ is a nonzero submodule then $S = d\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $d$ is the gcd of all integers which appear as entries of elements of $S$. This can be seen by repeated application of Bézout's identity.